# How to create table in SYS schema in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can one create table in sys schema SQL Server 2008 ?
I know it is possible to mark table as system, but not change the schema. 
Any hacks for it ?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: This is really not a good idea.  If you tell us WHY you want to do this we may be able to redirect you.

Comment: I don't even know. It's never crossed my mind probably because this sounds like the worst idea ever.

Comment: You may be able to change an objects schema via directly poking the system tables via the DAC, but as others have commented, I can see nothing good that could be achieved by doing this

Comment: Echoing a long line of WTH comments. It's highly likely if you did this, the DBMS would fall over in a big heap. What problem are you trying to solve with this 'erm less than brilliant solution?

Comment: Next thing they ask for is to redefine the `SELECT` keyword to actually execute a `DELETE` statement, and to redefine `TRUE` and `FALSE` :-)

Comment: Before it was possible to setup override system catalog protection in SQL Server 2005 and 2000 and setup schema manually.

Comment: I'm a system programmer and making some tricks for me is easier then writing tests to emulate behavior of system.

Comment: As I noted in Tim Lehner's answer below, sucessfully doing this would void your employer's MS support contract and product warranty.  So no responsible professional is going to tell you how to do it.  And especially not in a public forum.

Comment: @user1309871: It's easier to just fake your test results too, so why not do that instead? It certainly seems less irresponsible to me.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add your own objects to the sys schema.

> User-defined objects cannot be created in the sys schema.
>   Gail Erickson [MS]
>   SQL Server Documentation Team
>   This posting is provided "AS IS" with no warranties, and confers no rights

- Source: [How can I add an object to the sys schema in SQL Server 2005?](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/sys-schema-help-120271261.html)

If that's not convincing enough, consider that system objects are stored in the resource database, which is read-only:

> The Resource database is a read-only database that contains all the system objects that are included with SQL Server. SQL Server system objects, such as sys.objects, are physically persisted in the Resource database, but they logically appear in the sys schema of every database. The Resource database does not contain user data or user metadata.

- Source: [msdn - Resource Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940.aspx)

If there does exist some undocumented method to do this, as others have stated, it's probably not in your best interest (or that of your software and team) to do so.  I would suggest stepping back and attacking your problem from another angle.  Perhaps some sort of mock setup?

Comment: Actually, there is a way to do it, but since it would void the MS support contract and product warranty of anyone who did it, I am not going to post it publicly, and I'm certainly not going to instruct the OP in how to shoot his own foot off.  (I know you wouldn't do that, Tim, but everyone else who reads this is another story).

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

I use sql server 2012. Not sure if it works in older versions.

EXEC `sp_addextendedproperty N'microsoft_database_tools_support', N'migration log', N'schema', N'dbo', N'table', N'__MigrationHistory'`

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just what I needed. Works with 2005

Answer (score 2):

You've asked for a way to mark an object as a system object. There's an undocumented procedure called `sp_ms_marksystemobject` that does exactly that. There are some legitimate uses for this, but for the most part what you're trying to do is better accomplished without resulting to this. In short, weigh your options carefully before employing this. You've been forewarned.

Comment: Think you misread the question. They say "I **know** it is possible to mark table as system"