# How can I create a SQL Server system table

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing a site that uses Entity Framework code first with migrations. After each major release, I take a copy of the production data and set it up in my development environment. I've found that in order to use a production data copy with migrations, it is necessary to copy the `__MigrationHistory` table from the old development database image to the production database copy.

This works fine, except for one annoying detail: the `_MigrationHistory` table comes across as a user table instead of a system table. This is not a serious problem as long as I remember to filter it out of my database diffs. But I would prefer to have the new `__MigrationHistory` table be a system table, just as it is in a database that was created by EF migrations.

Is there a way I can create or copy a SQL Server table so that it appears to be a system table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand this is not a suggested practice.

[See TechNet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179932.aspx)

As a possible solution, I suggest declaring a new schema, such as ETL or Mig, and assigning security measures to that schema, if you are concerned about such things. This would serve to separate the '_MigrationHistory' Table from the rest of the user tables.

Edit:
Just found this in another question, maybe helpful if you are bent on doing this.
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986615/how-to-create-table-in-sys-schema-in-sql-server)

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because of the reference to the other question, which I was unable to find (this question is arguably a duplicate). I agree that using sp_ms_marksystemobject should be used with extreme caution, but I would argue that it's reasonable in this scenario.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following command change your table to system object. So it will then appear in System Objects.

```
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject _MigrationHistory
```